# Django and regex not working with primary keys

Tags: regex, django

Why this dont work? `State.objects.filter(pk__regex=r'^[0-9]')`

I get an error:

> no operator matches the given name and argument type(s)

Comment: Are you trying to pass a String into that filter?  Does it need double quotes around it, I am not familiar with django.

Comment: Solved :) Dont ask how but working :)

Answer (score 0):

Regex is for strings, but a pk is an integer.

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but if you want to just get all States with pk between 0 and 9, you can use range:

```
State.objects.filter(pk__range=(0, 9))
```